# Sacred Geometry of Chance

Tags: probability, geometry, optimization

**This problem is dedicated to [Leon the professional](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVYFOlVB-Uo)**.

This question came to my mind when I was contemplating on the numbers 1-20 arranged interestingly around a regular dartboard:

> **QUESTION:** Can we divide a circle with radius of $\sqrt{3}\sigma$ on a plain into **3** optimal pieces with equal areas assigned by
> $1,2,3$  as score ,which an ambitious dart player with density
> probability function of $f(r;\sigma )={\frac {r}{\sigma^{2}}}e^{-r^{2}/(2\sigma ^{2})}$ [(Rayleigh distribution)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuI61cTNbAk) as
> probability of dart hitting in distance of $r$ from his aim point,
> achieves **least** score from the designed dartboard plane in his
> throw (guaranty getting minimum **equal** score from each point on the
> board he may aim to shoot)?
>
> Are the shapes of these pieces unique? what are they look like?
>
> **Note1:** if dart goes out of the board player will get $0$ score. $\sigma$ is standard deviation in Rayleigh distribution and dart hits
> in circle of radius $\sigma$ around player's aim point by probability
> of about $0.39$.

*Note2:* At first I proposed a generalized form of this problem stating to find $n$ connected regions on a plane which they totally shape a connected closed board without any hole, assigned by $n$ natural numbers as score and the goal was to find optimal shape of each number ,But I found this simpler state of the problem as hard as enough to contemplate.

---Another Generalization can be considered: Setting a desired predefined probability score function over the dartboard plane domain(a function that you give a point of dartboard to it as input and it gives you the probable score achieves by a player who aim to hit that point as the output) and the challenge is to design a dartboard which gives us that predefined function as score probability in each point, like to design a deceiving dartboard which the score probability be least for points of region assigned by score $3$ and be highest for points of region assigned by score $1$. for easing the problem I have considered a constant probability score function with minimum value, which still finding its minimum value is challenging.

Note3: there can be other variants and generalizations of this problem which are more applied and even I think they maybe discussed earlier but it is great to discuss here too, for example in a combinatorics way a question arises where there are quantitative numbers of valuable sources in each country and a comet threaten the planet Earth with the same hitting probability for each of its points, the question here is how to divide these sources among different countries which we loose least number of sources when the comet hits (all of the sources become inaccessible in the whole country which has been hit).
However I hope this does not happen until we become advance enough in technology and facilities to eliminate such kind of threats by solving such these problems and also we human being be wise and united enough to use and benefit solutions in order to truly share our valuable sources.

**Ultimate Note:** the song ["shape of my heart"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuI61cTNbAk) from the film [leon the professional](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110413/) performed by Sting, which I like a lot, have also a very nice lyric. it says:

...

*He deals the cards to find the answer*

*The sacred geometry of chance*

*The hidden law of a probable outcome*

*The numbers lead a dance*

...

I am listening and singing the song while I'm still thinking about the problem: Is this life designed by God in a way which its "sacred geometry of chance" ,"the hidden law of its probable outcome",shapes our fate? what are the shapes look like?

would it be shape of my heart?...

Comment: Do you want this true for any $r$ in some range, or just for a specific $r$ to be supplied before you design the board?  If I know $r$ when I design the board it seems I should put an outer ring of $3$ because aiming at that will give a good chance of scoring $0$ by missing the board entirely.

Comment: I considered $r$ be the distance between point of hit and goal point so $r$ can be any number respect to error function

Comment: As you present it in the question, $r$ is the standard deviation of the miss distance, not the miss distance on one throw.  I was asking if we know that before we design the board or not.  I don't know if it is possible, but designing a board for a specific $r$ has to be easier than designing one for any $r$.

Comment: I think we can prove that you can't have the probability of hitting $1$ greater than the probability of $2$ or $3$ for any aim point.  What we can do is minimize the expected score by putting a lot of the $3$ area near the edge where he risks a $0$ for missing completely.  If we know $r$ in advance we can choose the thickness of the outer band.  You need to make the question precise.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I tried a lot to make the question as precise as I can, you got what i wanted to ask ,please help to make the question more appropriate and precise,thanks

Comment: In order to make more precise we need to define precise distribution function of hit map and the precise amount of area of the shapes which are related eachother

Comment: Standard deviation is shown by $\sigma$ ,but here r is distant variable dominates the error function, I accept that we have to predefine $\sigma$ proper to area of the shapes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79596/discussion-between-masm-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: I agree that this question needs more precision. It could be an interesting question if you work it out properly. In addition to the points raised by @RossMillikan, you should also clarify whether the overall shape of the board is given (and if so, what it is). Also, I don't understand what you mean by "the size of the board and the areas of the shapes are proper to the players distance range and so his error function" -- is this an answer to Ross's question? If so, I don't understand the answer.

Comment: @joriki precisely I was meaning the proportion between area of each shape and $\sigma$ the standard deviation of dart hit point from aim point be somehow rational ,which I have set it now $A=1/2 \pi\sigma^2$ . I have edited the problem, please check it out and say what we should add to make this problem more precise and solvable.thanks.

Comment: Changing the focus of a question after it has received an answer isn't fair to the answerer. Therefore, I'm going to roll this question back to its previous form (when it was specifically about the dart board question). If you want to expand the scope of discussion to "sacred geometry" or whatever, post a new question. (You can link back to this one for context.)

Comment: @Blue Thanks for your mentions ,but I haven't changed main question, just add some explanations about the problem ,so I think the answerer now has more options to think about

Comment: @Blue I added the explanations to the question and posted to overflow ,then it gets disappointing -7 vote and becomed "on hold" apparently because they called my explanation around the problem "noise around actual math" so I decided to replace these pages on mathexchange and mathoverflow as I hope in the community of mathexchange do not consider added explanations as "noises" at least.

Comment: @MasM: You should at least revert the title back to the "planar shapes..." version; By changing the title to mention "Sacred Geometry", and by including your musings "Is this life designed by God in a way which its sacred geometry of chance ...?", you make it seem like that is the new focus of a question that had been about dartboards. (BTW: "noise around the actual math" is a pretty good description of your edit —this is a question-and-answer site, not a blog— but I don't intend to get into a rollback battle over this.)

Comment: @Blue thanks for your comments ,I will make anothe page titled "sacred geometry of chance" later, but actually I didn't get what you say to do with this page in your last comment, please edit it in a way you consider better to fit with the community. Thanks

Comment: You want a way of assigning scores to points on the dartboard such that the expected score of the dart player, **when they play with an optimal strategy**, is minimized?

Comment: @Jack M no, the question is about to pre design a dartboard which the player achieves same equal minimum score from any point of dartboard he may aim to shoot, meaning exept from what point the player chooses to shoot ,the predesign guaranty to get constant. Pre calculated minimum score based on pre known probability distribution of the player's throw.

Comment: @MasM You want to make it so no matter where the player aims, they get the same expected score?

Comment: @Jack M Yes, getting same minimum expected score. The design shoud be in a way to give us 1.equal and 2.minimum expected score over whole dartboard's points(for being simple here we considerd a circle dart board to being divide into 3 pieces).the probability of getting score from each point be equal and minimum.

Answer (score 3):

We can clearly keep the average at $2$ or below.  Make three Archimedean spirals that wind around the center and have width per turn much smaller than $\sigma$.  Anywhere the player aims will have an equal mix of the three regions.  I think we can do a little better by having an outer ring of $3$ area.  If the player aims at that he has a fair chance of missing the board completely, and it allows the center of the board to be depleted in $3$ area.  Under this thought the solution would be three functions, each from a radius $[0,1]$ and giving the fraction of the circumference at that radius that is in each region $1,2,3$

Comment: Thanks for help, I assumed the proportion of $A=1/2 \pi\sigma^2$ between area $A$ of each shape and $\sigma$ but really I don't know what would differs in the problem by changin this proportion. Still I think the problem is not round enough to solve because of the ambiguity in asking minimal state of achieving scores probability in each board's point.

Comment: I was thinking one could make a simple model that chooses the outer ring of $3$ based on $\sigma$.  You assume that the area inside the ring is equally populated with $1,2$ and the rest of the $3$ area.  You choose the width of the $3$ ring so that the player can't improve over aiming at the center because too many shots fall outside the board.  I don't know if that will work and would have to develop a number of tools to do that.